# Random Freeze: Need help with mcelog

Tags: 14.04

My newly built computer freezes randomly. When it freezes, it doesn't respond to keyboards or mouses, so REISUB or ctrl+alt+f1 (or f2,f3.. etc) are of no use.

I had tried

- different graphic card drivers: the (fedora/ubuntu/win) defaults, the latest driver from Nvidia
- different OS: Ubuntu 14.04 (with UEFI boot), Fedora 23 (tried with or w.o. UEFI boot), Windows 10
- updating kernel
- swap memory stick: tried use only one stick, and placing it in different slots
- placing the graphic card in other PCI slots
- updating the bios from ASRock website
- disable firefox/chrome plugins/extensions. (at first I suspect the freeze is caused by browsers)

and the freeze still continues to occur.

I also did the following tests and they all report no errors:

- MemTest86: It ran for 16 hours and pass all 4 tests. Results is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVGmA.jpg)
- Glmark2 (to see how the graphic card performs. scores: 12688)
- Intel Processor Diagnostic Tool in Windows 10. Result is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezmmg342009qm27/CPU_Test.txt?dl=0)
- I also monitor the temperature and it remains below 60c

**Configuration:**

- Intel® Core™ i7-5960X
- ASRock X99X Killer LGA 2011-v3 Intel X99 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX Intel 
  Motherboard
- EVGA GeForce GTX 980
- SAMSUNG 850 EVO 2.5" 500GB SSD
- G.SKILL Ripjaws 4 Series 32GB (4 x 8GB) 288-Pin DDR4
- CORSAIR CX series CX600M 600W

I know this configuration looks like a gaming computer but **I've never played a game on it or overclocked**. The funniest finding in this frustrated situation is that the computer freezes at the most unexpected moments: It can freeze when I'm just using the file explorer + terminal. It sometimes freezes after watching YouTube for 30 minutes. But it never freezes when running diagnose tools. It also didn't freeze when I were running some python homework code and all 16 cpu-cores reach 100% usage.

**Question:**

Since the freezing happens across OS, I'm convinced that some of my hardware is broken. Below are the errors that mcelog shows, repeatedly. Can someone tells which part of my hardware is broken from the log? Or how can I understand it better?

Thanks!

```
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: Hardware event. This is not a software error.
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: MCE 0
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: CPU 0 BANK 17
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: MISC 8cf00031e0000086 ADDR 5f000000
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: TIME 1454088380 Fri Jan 29 09:26:20 2016
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: MCG status:
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: MCi status:
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: Error overflow
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: Uncorrected error
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: MCi_MISC register valid
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: MCi_ADDR register valid
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: Processor context corrupt
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: MCA: Generic CACHE Level-2 Eviction Error
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: STATUS ee2000000004017a MCGSTATUS 0
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: MCGCAP c16 APICID 0 SOCKETID 0
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 63
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: Hardware event. This is not a software error.
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: MCE 1
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: CPU 0 BANK 18
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: MISC 1cf00031e0000086 ADDR 5f100040
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: TIME 1454088380 Fri Jan 29 09:26:20 2016
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: MCG status:
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: MCi status:
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: Error overflow
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: Uncorrected error
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: MCi_MISC register valid
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: MCi_ADDR register valid
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: Processor context corrupt
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: MCA: Generic CACHE Level-2 Eviction Error
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: STATUS ee2000000004017a MCGSTATUS 0
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: MCGCAP c16 APICID 0 SOCKETID 0
    Jan 29 09:26:24 fedora23 mcelog[1004]: CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 63
```

Comment: Is this the entire log? Could you also run `mcelog --client` and post that. It looks like uncorrected memory errors.

Comment: The line `MCA: Generic CACHE Level-2 Eviction Error` points to a CPU Level-2 cache problem. You say you have run `Intel Processor Diagnostic Tool`; could you expand on it's findings?

Comment: Hello @Nathan, thanks for your reply. 
I took my computer to repair. I'll comment later when my computer is back.

Comment: Hello @Nathan, I have included the the result of the `Intel Processor Diagnostic Tool`. It seems normal.   

As for the mcelog, I have reinstalled my OS and cannot reproduce the error message (thanks god!).

Comment: Check the PSU and the motherboard. On the paper they're excellent, but I have an as much as excellent (indeed not as in "powerful", but as in "of quality") rig with a Corsair + EVGA P67 motherboard with the same problem, and couldn't check it yet since I've been using another PC for a quite a while now, but I highly suspect either the PSU or the motherboard not being able to handle the load while idling. If you can test with another PSU. Alternatively try to play with the BIOS' settings (try raising the vcore a little bit, in case it's dropping too much while idling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, there are two solutions for the freeze problem.

**1. Disable power-saving features:**   I disabled CPU C States Support in the BIOS, and in Ubuntu too following [this note](https://gist.github.com/wmealing/2dd2b543c4d3cff6cab7). Then I used the computer for a day and the freeze did not occur again. (It uses to freeze several times a day, in all operation systems.)

**2. Replace the motherboard:** Solution 1 seems to work but I prefer to keep the power-saving features enabled, so I still replace the motherboard (from Asrock X99X to Asus X99a). The computer has since been function normally.